# Use Javascript to CTRL+ and CTRL- in Firefox & Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome

I would like to give users the ability to increase/decrease the rendering size of the content inside of a web app.

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>-</kbd> features (or <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>9</kbd>) of Chrome & Firefox are handy - but is there a way from JavaScript to execute those features?

**Clarification:**
I want the user to be able to achieve this via mouse-clicks, not keypresses, so something like this:

```
function resize_rendering() {
    // code that executes ctrl+ or crtl-
}
```

Comment: I dont think you can mimic that feature of the browser since its a personal setting within the browser.  The CTRL+/- actually zooms in on all parts even images.  To do that with javascript you would have to increase the size of images and text on your site.  What I've seen is people just increasing the font size, using Javascript.. but not the images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The browser zoom level is a user setting, which is there for accessiblity purposes; it's not intended for the site developer to ever know or care what the zoom level is, so I would expect that you'll have trouble doing exactly what you want. Certainly, it'll be hard to get it right in a way that works cross-browser.

The normal approach to this is to have a sizing gadget that changes the base font size.

If all the font sizes in your site are in `em` units, then you can change the sizes of all the text on the site with a single CSS change.

So you would have a set of buttons on the site which use Javascript to set the `font-size` of the `<body>` element to (for example) 12, 14, 16 or 18 pixels, depending on the element clicked.

There's a write-up of the technique here: http://labnol.blogspot.com/2006/12/allow-site-visitors-to-change-font.html

Comment: That's what I figured, which is a bummer. Thanks :(

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to by design. You can't change a user's browser setting via Javascript.

You can do other things, like modify all of the CSS on your page to scale everything down to *simulate* a `CTRL-`, but that's all.

In some browsers you can capture CTRL+/- before the browser does, allowing you to stop those events from occuring. But you cannot do the oppisite - you cannot cause those events to occur from your own script.

Answer (score 0):

This library [here](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) by John Resig is a jQuery plugin that should do the job. There's some samples. Its quite easy to hookup combinations of keys as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could intercept the keystroke in a general key event handler (such as on the `window` object), check to see if it's the one you're looking for, and if so, call `stopPropagation()` on the event parameter (and return false) to prevent the browser from then handling it on its own.

You'd then have to perform the sizing operation yourself, such as by modifying a stylesheet using JavaScript.

```
window.addEventListener( 'keydown', function( e ) {
    if ( /* check e.keyCode etc. */ ) {
        // modify global style to increase/decrease font size
        e.stopPropagation();
        return false;
    } );
```

Comment: I am actually looking for a way to do this WITHOUT user having to use keypresses (perhaps a slider, or something else like that they can use)

Comment: Ah sorry, misunderstood the question. It's certainly possible to do it using controls on a web page that modify the base style sheet as I suggested. But I don't know if it's possible to actually call into the browser's native functionality.

Comment: you didn't mis-understand, it was my fault. I re-read my question and it was vague, so I added clarification. Thanks for the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Look towards CSS property "zoom"

```
/* ctrl++ */
body {
   zoom: 1.1;
}
```

For JS, it's like:

```
function resize_rendering(zoom) {
   let currentZoom = parseFloat(document.body.style.zoom) || 1
   document.body.style.zoom = currentZoom * zoom
}

resize_rendering(1.1) // ctrl++
resize_rendering(0.9) // ctrl+-
```